# Script doesnt run from another script

Tags: powershell, execution

I compiled an AutoIt script and uploaded it to a server. I then wrote a PowerShell script which downloads the compiled AutoIt script and runs it locally.

When I run the PowerShell script on Windows 7 it runs without issues. But when I run the PowerShell script from an application, the compiled AutoIt script does get downloaded but does not run to completion. It does appear in task manager.

Comment: You should post the script or at least the main part of it. Otherwise it's nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29767934/4157124).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the script it is hard to say for sure. However, it might be a rights issue. Try adding this to the top of your script and see if it fixes the problem.

```
#RequireAdmin
```